# Vue router isLoading show loader div in App.vue

Tags: vue.js, vite, loader, preloader

I have a simple problem.

I'm using Vue3 with vite, typescript and router, and I can't figure out, how to trigger a loading screen whilst the user clicks on router paths.

I successfully understood and implemented that within the `router/index.ts`, I can call a `router.beforeEach`, in which I can toggle a variable. Called it `isLoading`, and put a `timeout` delay before another route is rendered, it looks as follows:

```
var isLoading = false

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) =>{
  console.log("beforeach");
  isLoading = true
  console.log(isLoading)

setTimeout(() => {
  next();
}, 2000);


});
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  console.log("aftereach");
  var isLoading = false
  console.log(isLoading)

});
```

In my App.vue, I have a `Preloader` component imported from my `views` folder, which contains a simple div with some styling, and I want this component to get a class on `beforeEach`, and that class to be gone on `afterEach`.

But I have no idea, how to acquire the state of `isLoading` from my `router/index.ts`, or, if there is another way purely within App.vue that could trigger a class to my PreLoader component.

Thanks for your help!

Tried to use beforeEach and afterEach with a delay within router/index.ts, but don't know how to export the state of isLoading to App.vue.

Answer (score 3):

so thanks to Neha Soni's answer, I found out about

```
Pinia
```

and what I had in mind, looks like the following:

I installed pinia, created a *`store`* folder under *`src`*, and created there an *`isloading.ts`* file, which looks like this:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { reactive, ref } from "vue";

export const  useLoaderState = defineStore("isLoading", () => {
    
    const state = ref(false)

const changeStateTrue = () => {
    state.value = true
}

const changeStateFalse = () => {
    state.value = false
}

    return { state, changeStateTrue, changeStateFalse }
})
```

In **`router/index.ts`**, I have the following logic that awaits for a bit before actually rendering the clicked route, and saves to the global variable isLoading as state a boolean:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const isLoading = useLoaderState();
  const { changeStateTrue } = isLoading;
  
  console.log("beforeach");
  changeStateTrue();
  console.log(isLoading.state);

  setTimeout(() => {
    next();
  }, 500);
});
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  const isLoading = useLoaderState();
  const { changeStateFalse } = isLoading;

  console.log("aftereach");
  changeStateFalse();
  console.log(isLoading.state);
});
```

Finally, in my **`App.vue`** I have the following for my PreLoader, which is just for a loading screen:

```
 <script setup lang="ts">
   import { useLoaderState } from "./store/isloading";

   const isLoading = useLoaderState();
  </script>

  <template>
          <PreLoader v-if="isLoading.state" :class="[currentTheme]" />
  </template>
```

I wanted even my loader to change according to the already applied dark/light mode, so thats what the `:class="[currentTheme]"` is there for, what is important is the `v-if="isLoading.state"` , which first gets into this component with calling the Pinia way the **`isLoading`** global variable with

- importing the defined store with        `import { useLoaderState } from "./store/isloading";`
- creating a constant in this current `App.vue` with the        `const isLoading = useLoaderState();`

From there, the constant's values and states (including the boolean which I wanted) lives reactively in this current component (in this case, the `App.vue`), and the `v-if` will get updated therefore dynamically.

Comment: Haha, didn't know, thx for the tip :) Well it says "You can accept your own answer in 2 days", but yeah

Answer (score 1):

The following two approaches can help you-

**1. Using event bus-**

- Emit an event on the router's before and after hook and pass a status true/false.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) =>{
  eventbus.emit('loader-status', true)
});
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  eventbus.emit('loader-status', true)
});
```

- Listen to this event in your loader component and show/hide the loader as per the status passed by the event.

```
eventbus.on('loader-status', status => { this.showLoader = status })
```

Here you can read- [How to use event buses in vue3.](https://medium.com/@certosinolab/using-event-bus-in-vue-js-3-425aae8c21a6)

**2. Using Vuex-**

- Create a variable named `showLoader` in the Vuex state.
- Update that variable on routers before and after the hook.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) =>{
  // call a mutation to update the showLoader to true
});
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  // call a mutation to update the showLoader to false
});
```

3. Use this global variable's value in the Loader component to show/hide the loader.

```
<Loader v-if="store.state.showLoader"></Loader>
```

Here you can read- [How to set up Vuex in vue3.](https://auth0.com/blog/state-management-in-vue-3-applications/)

**NOTE-**
I only provided the logical code, syntax would be different when you use any of the above approaches.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your very thorough answer!
Second, due to your help, I found out about Pinia, and it wasn't easy to wrap my head around it, exactly what it does and how to get states and values from a globally saved variable (saving in eg. "isLoading" a state, then I first tried getting just "isLoading" if true or false, then realising, the state part is whats get changed...), I finally managed to reactively change these Pinia global variables, and reactively get it in my component (App.vue). Going to post the solution